# Can we use user defined classes defined in parent project into child project maven?

Tags: java, apache, maven

We can inherit dependencies from parent project into child project in maven. But I am no able to use classes defined in parent project into child project.
Do I need to add parent project into dependencies of child project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parent and child project probably assumes that you use maven's inheritance feature.

Here is what's written in [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance)

```
The packaging type required to be pom for parent and aggregation (multi-module) projects.
```

So, your parent project should be with packaging type "pom" and enlist your child projects that can be of packaging jar or even pom if they have children in turn.
But in this case, the parent project cannot really contain the java code, so your question is kind of confusing here

When it comes to dependencies in a parent project, yes, if you define dependencies on parent pom they'll be automatically inherited by all children projects
In the same section of the link I've provided above, you can find a list of elements that get inherited and dependencies section appears there.

If you want to reuse your own code between many modules you should just create a module with packaging jar (regular maven module), put the shared code there and then in other modules, just declare the dependency on your shared module.